# css only textured and 'stitched' ribbon

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

This is driving me nuts, I've seen it before but can't replicate it or find it or any resources for it. What I am doing is a vertical ribbon with a leather texture and a "stitched pattern". The way the stitches work is simple enough, inner divs with dashed borders, and even the ribbon shape is easy enough using the pseudo `:after` class, but combining the two is just not going to plan.

This is what I have for css that is working so far (it is all done with css minus the leather texture):

```css
.wrapleather {
        width:100px;
        height:120px;
     float: right;
     margin-right:20px;
        background-image : url("leather.png");
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     position:relative;
    }
    .wrapleather:after {
     content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 105px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-width: 0 50px 15px 50px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent transparent #cdc0a8;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
    }
    .wrapleather .outside {
     width:90px;
     height:110px;
        margin: 4px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px dashed #aaa;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #f5f5f5;
     }
    .wrapleather .inside {
        width:90px;
        height:110px;
        border-radius: 5px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="wrapleather">
     <div class="outside">
       <div class="inside">
        <p class="font">Leather</p>
       </div>
     </div>    
  </div>
```

Additionally the shadow is remaining in a "square" format and not taking the shape of everything. To clarify I am not asking anyone to debug or anything like that, I am simply asking for alternative or further methods to be shared that could achieve the desired results, css is still something I am in the process of learning so any advice or anything of that nature that you could give would be appreciated, and if you need any additional info please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably multiple background gradients.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: @zenkaty html is up, rather simple. @ Ariel can you clarify?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the fact that the stitches aren't following the shape of the 'ribbon'? As the 'shape' is just fat borders (very clever, btw) I don't know of a way to get the border of the other one to follow it... sorry! Same deal with the shadows - they apply to the shape, they don't 'know' what you've drawn on the top with borders.

Comment: @zenkaty Yes that's spot on, and I can't take credit for it, I found it some time ago in a css blog, but it is clever. I was assuming the borders if applied to the classes that create the stitch affect would create the same shape but that was not the case unfortunately. Perhaps I was doing it wrong though. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I would probably use an image for the background, but if you want to stick to CSS-only, then simplify the shape - remove the shadows and maybe just have the stitching on the vertical lines, not the bottom part. Not a very good solution, I know! EDIT: like this http://jsfiddle.net/YxS6g/

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I do want to keep it css though; that should hold me over until I do find a fix at least, thanks!

Comment: another thought: you could add the same dashed border style in a darker colour to .inside for "shadows" on the stitches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way to do what you want with CSS only, but it won't work on all browsers. If you want the best browser support, you should probably use an image.

Here is a demo (you may have noticed I only use a single element, as you shouldn't introduce extra markup just for styling): http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/eUje5/

```
HTML

<div class="ribbon"></div>
```

​

```
CSS

.ribbon {
    background: #eee;
    border-left: 1px dashed #aaa;
    border-right: 1px dashed #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 0 #eee,
                -5px 0 0 #eee;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.5));
}
.ribbon:after,
.ribbon:before {
    border-top: 15px solid #eee;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
.ribbon:after {
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    right: -6px;
}
.ribbon:before {
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    left: -6px;
}
```

Comment: @joshnh, can you accomplish the webkit-filter property in other browsers as well?

Answer (score 0):

So, I wanted to make sure that I wasn't losing my mind and that this ribbon effect is actually possible on modern browsers without relying on webkit specific filters.  So here it is for all those who come across this later.

You just need to be more diligent with how you model your `box-shadows`.

Note that when increasing the width, you'll need to subsequently decrease the angle at which you're rotating and skewing the `:before` and `:after` elements.

Example:

```css
.ribbon {
    background: #eee;
    border-left: 1px dashed #aaa;
    border-right: 1px dashed #aaa;
    border-top: 1px dashed #aaa;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 0 #eee,
                -5px 0 0 #eee,
                0 -5px 0 #eee,
                5px -5px 0 #eee,
                -5px -5px 0 #eee,
                5px 1px 5px 5px #888;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.ribbon:after,
.ribbon:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 1px);
    width: calc(50% + 1px);
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
}
.ribbon:after {
    transform: rotateZ(20deg) skewX(20deg) translateY(-2px);
    transform-origin: top right;
    right: -1px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-right: 1px dashed #aaa;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 0 #eee,
                0 5px 0 #eee,
                5px 5px 0 #eee,
                15px 15px 5px -5px #888,
                0 15px 5px -5px #888,
                15px 0 5px -5px #888;
}
.ribbon:before {
    transform: rotateZ(-20deg) skewX(-20deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    left: -1px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-left: 1px dashed #aaa;
    box-shadow: -5px 0 0 #eee,
                0 5px 0 #eee,
                5px 5px 0 #eee,
                15px 15px 5px -5px #888,
                0 15px 5px -5px #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon"></div>
```